# Visa denied with reason INA212a6ci although the interview was successful

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, fraud

My sister went for an interview with US embassy on Jan 2020 and it was successful, they took her passport and literally said congratulations. Today, we received a refused letter with the passport and the reason is INA212a6ci which is a waiver for fraud or misrepresentation. Somebody please explain me the reason for this case since we were honest about everything.

Comment: What does the letter say?

Comment: Denial for this reason means permanent ineligibility, unless your sister can apply for a waiver https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-denials.html You’ll probably need an immigration lawyer to stand any chance of resolving this.

Comment: Did your sister submit her own application, or did she use an agent? It's not uncommon for less reputable agents to 'help' an application by adding fraudulent documents. Immigration staff will hold the applicant responsible for this, even if they were unaware. Traveller is right: she needs a lawyer.

Comment: Actually me and my bro had an interview before her (1-2 months before) and we were approved and got visa already. My sis literally got the same result but when they returned passport, they sent with a blue letter saying my sis was refused due to above reason. We don't get what is going on...

Comment: We applied all documents and stuff by ourselves, we didn't have any agents do it.

Comment: Sorry the interview was on 6 Jan 2020 not 2019

Comment: Interviewer said "congratulations, your visa is approved " and sent her some advises also good luck in US blah blah, they took her passport and photo and said the visa will be returned in 2-3 working days and finally we got that result :(

Comment: What does the letter say?

Comment: It said my sis WAS REFUSED UNDER INA 212 FOR MISREPRESENTATION, WHICH IS CONSIDERED A SEVERE CASE

Comment: Can you upload a scan of the letter, with personal details redacted?

Comment: I wonder whether it's a good idea to ask the embassy or consulate whether there was a clerical error, in light of the visa officer's words of congratulations.  What documents did you submit with the application?

Comment: What's the nationality of your sister? Did the diplomatic relations between your nation and the U.S. change recently? Because of [this](https://thediplomat.com/2019/12/china-tries-to-put-sweden-on-ice/) I was denied a multiple-entry to China (got single though), and I've heard of more cases like that. Even a pair of brothers who applied with a month difference got different outcome which sounds like a less sever version of your situation.

Comment: @pipe I would not think that chaining someone to a denial for deception -- which results in lifetime inadmissibility -- is the usual mechanism for refusing visas when diplomatic relations change.

Answer (score 6):

So the interview was successful but something else was found that led to her refusal. It could have been found before the interview and the interviewer did not know yet, after the interview, or while checking something she stated in the interview.

All the information is at https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-denials.html

The embassy has found you materially misrepresented something on your application or during the process. NA212a6ci means she can never get a visa unless this is resolved. Your only recourse is for your sister or her lawyer (not a relative) to contact the embassy or consulate to seek clarification. No other recourse exists. The reason for denial, the process, and who to contact are all spelled out at the above link.